# Memory performance vs Utilization

Tags: performance, memory

**Question:** How is memory (RAM) performance (read/write speeds, etc.) affected by total utilization.

**Background:**

- I am curious if there is a performance impact for reading/writing to system memory based on the overall utilization of that memory
- If performance degrades at higher utilization, what is the relationship between utilization and performance? Is this linear? Or at some point is there a significant drop in performance?
- If there is a drop in performance with higher utilization, is there a point at which it becomes faster to use swap on an SSD on a SATA bus? Where does this point occur?

**Outcome:**
All else being equal, I'm curious if there should be a specific target for memory utilization to get the best performance from a machine as on the one hand, having more stuff in system memory should make things faster than having to read from disk, but at some point surely, the overall memory performance is materially affected by some overhead from high memory utilization right?

Comment: Individual accesses to system memory will, of course, always be much faster than an access to any cache level or persistent store and will not be affected by memory utilization.  Of course, there are also data models whose efficiency declines as available system memory decreases.  So ... take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like a superuser.com question, not stackoverflow.

Time to allocate new memory might increase slightly as the system approaches 100% full.

If you don't have any swap space, Linux will pick a processes using a lot of RAM and kill it pre-emptively when the system is approaching OOM.  (google oom-killer.)

Access time to already allocated memory is not at all influenced by the fraction of total memory in use.  A program that uses 1GB of memory with some specific access pattern will show the same performance on a machine with 2G vs. a machine with 16GB of RAM.

Virtual->physical mappings are defined by page tables, which by themselves could give slower performance for lookups when more memory is allocated to a process.  (each process has its own page table).  Again, this is not %-full dependent, simply size.  However, these lookups need to be cached by the CPU hardware TLB.

See [Ulrich Drepper's What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf) for more background on this stuff.